Can't boot into duplicated partition -- grub issue?
I can't seem to boot out of the Xubuntu 20.04 in a duplicated partition to my initial / root partition.
My only operable OS on my machine was Xubuntu 20.04, mounted as / on a partition nvme0n1p3. I wanted to add another partition and install the root / mount point for Ubuntu 24.04 into it. I ran into issues whereby the manual partitioner couldn't recognize my /boot/efi partition (similar to this). My guess at the moment is that Ubuntu 24.04 can't proceed with the install because it requires that initial partition to be 1 GiB, not the 512 MiB that more than sufficed under Xubuntu 20.04.
SO, I'm trying to make space to enlarge that first partition, which means I need to effectually move the nvme0n1p3. The steps that made the most sense were to:

create a new partition (nvme0n1p4) off the end of the current nvme0n1p3 partition, with a gap of 2 GiB
Duplicate the old Xubuntu 20.04 from the original (nvme0n1p3) to the new partition (nvme0n1p4)
Once convinced that I can boot and run out of the duplicated (nvme0n1p4) partition, delete the original partition ((nvme0n1p3)
Resize the vfat /boot/efi partition to 2.5 GiB (more than necessary, but a precaution against similar issues in the future)
Create a new nvme0n1p3 partition (it might not get called that) between the boot and nvme0n1p4 partitions, but just leave it empty for now
Create a new partition (nvme0n1p5) partition in the unallocated space to the "right" of the existing partitions, and eventually install (hopefully) Ubuntu 24.04 into it.

I'm stuck between steps 2 and 3. The finer detail is:

Use gparted to do the partitioning described above
Re-boot off of the Ubuntu 24.04 USB stick (so that all partitions can be unmounted)
dd the existing nvme0n1p3 partition to the new nvme0n1p4 partition
Follow along here to give the new partition a unique UUID and edit the /etc/fstab entry in the nvme0n1p4 partition accordingly
Run update-grub, and confirm new menu entries in /boot/grub/grub.cfg
Attempt to boot into the cloned-Xubuntu 20.04 nvme0n1p4 partition

I am apparently able to select the right menu option in the grub menu, but it boots me into the original nvme0n1p3 partition.
Some details:
sudo lsblk -f:
nvme0n1



-
-
-
-
-
-




├─nvme0n1p1
vfat
995C-7BB0
469M
1%
/boot/efi


├─nvme0n1p2
swap
e67db830-5b33-41bb-859d-8ab967d79db6


[SWAP]


├─nvme0n1p3
ext4
63c24e20-9e18-4b6d-9091-5289f1398d61
21.8G
65%
/


├─nvme0n1p4
ext4
e3a93f78-5ba8-445a-9a9f-bcd95aabd7dd





└─nvme0n1p5
ext4
d777c31a-6fb1-4b27-bedd-1d5400569eee






sudo fdisk -l



Device
Start
End
Sectors
Size
Type




/dev/nvme0n1p1
2048
976895
974848
476M
EFI System


/dev/nvme0n1p3
976896
157227007
156250112
74.5G
Linux filesystem


/dev/nvme0n1p4
161323008
325163007
163840000
78.1G
Linux filesystem


/dev/nvme0n1p5
325163008
489003007
163840000
78.1G
Linux filesystem


/dev/nvme0n1p2
945522688
976771071
31248384
14.9G
Linux swap



I understand that one shouldn't edit the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file directly, but I'm a little puzzled at entries like

menuentry 'Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (20.04) (on /dev/nvme0n1p4)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-simple-e3a93f78-5ba8-445a-9a9f-bcd95aabd7dd' {
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  e3a93f78-5ba8-445a-9a9f-bcd95aabd7dd
else
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e3a93f78-5ba8-445a-9a9f-bcd95aabd7dd
fi
linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-127-generic root=UUID=63c24e20-9e18-4b6d-9091-5289f1398d61 ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-127-generic
}

update-grub appears to pick up the new UUID through most of the entry, but ultimately retains the old UUID in the "linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-127-generic" line. If this is the problem, update-grub is evidently getting the wrong info from somewhere I haven't found yet. Is that the problem? What else am I missing?
update-grub itself doesn't suggest there should be any problems:

Sourcing file '/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file '/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-127-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-127-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-125-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-125-generic
Found Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (20.04) on /dev/nvme0n1p4
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done

EDIT/ADDED: Curiously, the non-booting nvme0n1p4 partition is in the os-prober portion of grub.cfg. This suggests it should be in the 10_linux section. update-grub seems to be getting it wrong?
Edit #2:  The answer in this question convinced me to go off piste and edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg by hand and try rebooting. I moved the nvme0n1p4 partition / root to the 10_linux section, and replaced the ...-5289f1398d61 lines to ...-bcd95aabd7dd. Selecting the same menu item as before this time booted me into this partition. So, success, except I wasn't supposed to edit that file by hand.
And, running (this time) sudo update-grub2, the original nvme0n1p3 / root winds up in the 30_os-prober section, the expected reciprocal of before, though this time all UUIDs in all the menu and submenu blocks show ...-5289f1398d61.

Why didn't you add manual entries to /etc/grub.d/40_custom instead of editing /boot/grub/grub.cfg?

Because I had no idea about that, and nothing about it came up with the way I was searching for clues. It's odd that this would be the expected workflow, though, no? (1) let update-grub treat the duplicated partition as a foreign OS, then copy and correct that entry into 40_custom?

I do not thing what you are doing is unusual. I think you had GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true set in /etc/default/grub and the os prober did not quite work correctly. This is does happen. You manually changed /boot/grub/grub.cfg to fix errors. You can now set GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false and manually put the Grub menu entries in /etc/grub.d/40_custom.
